# How to avoid rehashing dict keys?

Tags: python, set

The script below illustrates a capability of `set` and `frozenset` that I would like to understand, and, if possible replicate in a subclass of collections.MutableSet.  (BTW, this feature is not just a oddity of `set` and `frozenset`: it is actively verified in Python's unit tests for these types.)

The script performs the following steps for each of several types/classes of set-like objects:

1. create a dict `d` whose `n` keys are specially instrumented integers that keep track of how many times their `__hash__` method is invoked (`d`'s values are all `None`, but this is irrelevant);
2. compute (and save for later) the cumulative number of times the `__hash__` method of `d`'s keys has been called so far (i.e. during the creation of `d`);
3. create an object `s` of the current set-like type/class, using `d` as the argument to the constructor (hence, `d`'s keys will become the contents of the resulting object, whereas `d`'s values will be ignored);
4. redo the calculation described in (2);
5. output the results from calculations from (2) and (4) above.

Here's the output for the case where `n` is set to 10 for all types/classes (I give the full code at the end of this post):

```
set: 10 10
frozenset: 10 10
Set: 10 20
myset: 10 20
```

The conclusion is clear: constructing a `set` or a `frozenset` from `d` does not require invoking the `__hash__` method of `d`'s keys, hence the call counts remain unchanged after these constructors return.  This is not the case, however, when instances of `Set` or `myset` are created from `d`.  In each of these cases it appears that each of `d`'s keys' `__hash__` is invoked once.

> How can I modify `myset` (see below) so that running its constructor with `d` as its argument results in no calls to `d`'s keys' hash methods?

Thanks!

```
from sets import Set
from collections import MutableSet

class hash_counting_int(int):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.count = 0
    def __hash__(self):
        self.count += 1
        return int.__hash__(self)

class myset(MutableSet):
    def __init__(self, iterable=()):
        # The values of self.dictset matter!  See further notes below.
        self.dictset = dict((item, i) for i, item in enumerate(iterable))

    def __bomb(s, *a, **k): raise NotImplementedError
    add = discard = __contains__ = __iter__ = __len__ = __bomb

def test_do_not_rehash_dict_keys(thetype, n=1):
    d = dict.fromkeys(hash_counting_int(k) for k in xrange(n))
    before = sum(elem.count for elem in d)
    s = thetype(d)
    after = sum(elem.count for elem in d)
    return before, after

for t in set, frozenset, Set, myset:
    before, after = test_do_not_rehash_dict_keys(t, 10)
    print '%s: %d %d' % (t.__name__, before, after)
```

Note that, the values of `self.dictset` are integers, and are pointedly *not* the same as the (ignored) `iterable.values()` (in those cases where `iterable.values` actually exists)!  This is an attempt (admittedly feeble) to indicate that, even when `iterable` is a dict (which need not be the case) and its `values` are ignored, in the real code that this example is standing in for, the `values` of `self.dictset` are *always* significant.  This means that any solution based on using `self.dictset.update(iterable)` still has to solve the problem of assigning the proper values to its keys, and once again one faces the problem of iterating over these keys without invoking their `__hash__` methods.  (In addition, solutions based on `self.dictset.update(iterable)` also have to solve the problem of properly handling the case when `iterable` is not a suitable argument for `self.dictset.update`, although this problem is not insurmountable.)

Edits: 1) clarified the significance of myset.dictset's values; 2) renamed `myset.__bomb__` to `myset.__bomb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the most basic level, it's rehashing the keys because you pass a genex to `dict` instead of a mapping.

You could try this:

```
class myset(MutableSet):
    def __init__(self, iterable=()):
        self.dictset = {}
        self.dictset.update(iterable)

    def __bomb__(s, *a, **k): raise NotImplementedError
    add = discard = __contains__ = __iter__ = __len__ = __bomb__
```

Output:

```
set: 10 10
frozenset: 10 10
Set: 10 20
myset: 10 10
```

`update` accepts a genex too, but if `iterable` is a mapping, Python is smart enough not to rehash the keys. Indeed, you don't even have to create the dict separately as above. You can just do `dict(mapping)` as long as you don't encapsulate it within a genex. But you've indicated that you also want to *change* the value associated with the key. This is possible in a sense, with `dict.fromkeys(mapping, default_val)`: you can specify a default value in that case, and all keys will take that value, but because you pass a mapping, nothing will be rehashed. But that's still not enough, I'm guessing; you seem to want to give a new *and unique* value to each key.

So your *real* question is, very simply, is it possible to assign a new value to a key without rehashing the key. And when phrased that way, perhaps you can see that it's not possible in a straightforward way.

In general, there's no built-in way to change the value of an arbitrary key:value pair without rehashing the key. This is for two reasons:

1. When assigning a value to an arbitrary key, Python needs to know both the key *and* its hash, in case there's a collision. Python *could* allow you to pass both a key and a pre-calculated hash, but then you could really screw things up by passing an inconsistent hash. So it's better for all of us to let Python do the bookkeeping there. The overhead of calling `__hash__` is worth it. (Note that in at least some cases, Python caches the hash — in those cases, this just looks up the cached hash.)
2. The other way to change a value would be to change the pointer value stored at some particular memory address that the `dict` points to, which you have saved and associated with the key. This, very simply, involves exposing *way* too much of Python's internal structure. However, this approach is the basis of a hackish solution detailed below.

Now, Python itself can efficiently *merge* two dictionaries by manipulating `dict` internals, because 1 isn't valid in that case; it is guaranteed that all collisions have been dealt with already! But again, those internals shouldn't be exposed. With `fromkeys`, Python probably does something akin to 2 internally, but the default value is always the same. I can imagine a situation where Python would offer another keyword extension to `fromkeys` that would accept a *function* instead of a default value; it would call the function with the associated key and use the returned value. That would be cool. But it doesn't exist.

So our *only* hope is to do something hackish. Since we very simply *can't* change the value  associated with a dict key without rehashing, we'll simply have to associate the key with a *mutable* value.

```
>>> a = dict((hash_counting_int(x), []) for x in range(10))
>>> [x.count for x in a.keys()]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> b = dict(a)
>>> [x.count for x in a.keys()]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> for n, v in enumerate(b.itervalues()):
...     v.append(n)
... 
>>> [x.count for x in a.keys()]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> b
{0: [0], 1: [1], 2: [2], 3: [3], 4: [4], 5: [5], 6: [6], 7: [7], 8: [8], 9: [9]}
```

This is, unfortunately, the only possible solution that doesn't involve mucking about in `dict`'s internals. And I hope you agree that it's not a very good one.

Comment: The problem with this approach (which I had considered) is that, whereas, when `iterable` is a dict, its values are irrelevant, the values of `self.dictset` always matter (I tried to signal this by giving them non-`None` values in my example code, though, granted, I should have made this point more explicit).  In this case, the problem shifts to initializing the values of the newly `update`'d `self.dictset`, and I'm back to where I started...

Comment: Ah, I see. When you said "`d`'s values are all `None`, but this is irrelevant", I took you to be saying that _all_ values are irrelevant, and that your only concern was for keys. So your _real_ question is, very simply, is it possible to assign a new value to a key without rehashing the key. And when phrased that way, perhaps you can see that it's not possible in direct way. See my answer for a continuation...

Comment: Thank you for the careful explanation.  I've learned a lot from your post (and still learning, actually).

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong both don't you mean 'key' every time when you talk about 'value' in your reply?

Comment: @Elmex80s, though it has been a very long time indeed since I last looked at this, I don't believe I do. I can help clarify if you explain why you think that though. Edit: Looking back over my answer, there is *one* spot where I use "value" to mean "the value of the key," which is admittedly confusing.

Comment: If you have to re-hash the key like you say, then how could you find out at all which key-value pair  to update? Because when you update the value to a key you have to select / find the key by its hash first.

Comment: @Elmex80s, you say "when you update the value to a key you have to select / find the key by its hash first." That's exactly why you need to re-hash it. How do you know the hash otherwise?

Comment: I see, I was confused and thought re-hashing meant calculating a new *different* hash. Assuming the key didn't mutated, every time you hash you will find the same output of course.